# Error from server (Forbidden): pods "my-pod" is forbidden: User "system:node:i

Tags: amazon-eks

I'm getting error while running command `kubectl get all` within EC2 managed worked node.

I've installed ssm agent on eks node using DameonSet in AWS EC2 and connect worker node using System Manager.

Getting same error while trying to interect with running pod using command
`kubectl exec -it my-pod-id -- sh`

```
Error from server (Forbidden): pods "my-pod-id" is forbidden: User "system:node:ec2-ip-address.aws-region.compute.internal" cannot create resource "pods/exec" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
```

Comment: i was able to resolve this after adding   subject {
    kind      = "User"
    name      = "user-id"
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  } in kubernetes_cluster_role_binding.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit clusterRolebinding(system:node),add this subject:-

```
subjects:
  - kind: User
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    name: system:node:*
```

, you can also customize it's clusterRole it's exist inside it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).